# MoveIt ! Rviz plugin show mutiple pr2 model in disorder when I fellow the quick start tutorial

Tags: ros, moveit, rviz-plugins, motion-planners

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to follow the quick start tutorial of the MoveIt. When I use rviz plugin to show the pr2 model and try to interact with the pr2. The tutorial can be found at MoveIt webside.
but the problem is that when I launch the demo.launch file.The rviz show pr2 in disorder (sometime pr2 is lying on the ground,sometime pr2 is hanging in the air),and the pr2 model dynamicly change in the rviz .

what is the problem?who can help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/103066/moveit-!-rviz-plugin-show-mutiple-pr2-model-in-disorder-when-i-fellow-the-quick-start-tutorial/) by [ShareIQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/9001/shareiq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-11-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I install the ros groovy instead of ros hydro,and the problem disappear! Maybe the MoveIt! in hydro version is not stable enough!

---

Originally posted by [ShareIQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/9001/shareiq/) with karma: 16 on 2013-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0